# RabbitMQ PHP driver (AMQP): handling blocked connections

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqplib

I am trying to build meaningful code to handle situation when RabbitMQ starts to block connections because of disk level or memory watermark alert.

There is a possibility to add handler for notifications about setting the connection into blocked mode.

However, it seems that this notification is sent only when I try to close connection.

So running

```
$this->channel->basic_publish($msg, $this->exchangeName, $route);
```

executes successfully, handler doesn't receive notification about blocked connection.

At the same time, message is not added to queue - I can tell it from dashboard.

But when I try to close connection explicitly:

```
$this->channel->close();
```

or implicitly (by just letting script to finish, AMQP object destructor does the rest) I receive notification that channel is blocked and after that script just freezes as, as far as I understand, it waits for some data to finish close_ok method.

So the question is how to get info about blocked channel at time (or just after) of publishing? And how to avoid script waiting forever on blocked connection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it looks like I have an answer.

RabbitMQ posts notifications to **active** connections.

So if I try to create connection to server that experience memory or disk problems those notifications are not helping at all.

But if connection is active then notification about blocking arrive just after I try to publish message, as it should be.

Now I just need to figure out how to detect that server is experiencing issues on stage of creating new connection. But this is another question.

Comment: Did you figure something out? Experiencing a similar issue right now